# MySQL Total Time For A Mode

Tags: mysql

This is my first ever post on a forum...
I am trying to teach myself MySQL for my home solar project, but have hit a snag. I am recording data from an inverter to a DB every 5sec (This can be more sometimes i.e missed poll or inerter busy...) but now I need to know how long the inverter was in one of it's two modes in a period of time (The inverter can switch modes several times in a day).

Here is a small extract from my table:

```
ID      Date_Time           Work_Mode
-----------------------------------------------
30039   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30041   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30042   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30044   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30046   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30048   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30050   2016-01-16 04:31    Line Mode
30052   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30053   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30055   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30057   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30059   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30061   2016-01-16 04:32    Line Mode
30063   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30065   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30067   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30069   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30071   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30073   2016-01-16 04:32    Battery Mode
30075   2016-01-16 04:33    Battery Mode
```

I have read tons up and have been trying for the last week and cannot resolve this, any assistance will be most welcome...

Comment: based upon this data set, what would the desired result set look like?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky that approach will fail horribly once you switch back and forth between modes twice. Aggregation cannot solve this with this input.

Comment: The result I am looking for is between Date_Time and Date_Time: Battery Mode = X Hours and Line Mode = X Hours

Answer (score 1):

RDBMS'es cannot (efficiently) do vertical logic like what you would need here, dynamically finding the first and last **consecutive** occurrence of a field. Your data model is highly inefficient, and I would recommend changing it to a from/to format, with the to-field `NULL` for the current mode. If that is impossible, the only realistic way of solving this is denormalizing the raw data in code, if required to an intermediate to/from table.